# jQuery file uploader chunk uploads stop without exception

Tags: file-upload, upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the [jQuery File Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) to implement chunked file uploads, broken down into 2MB chunks. The uploader works fine when testing on localhost, as well as DSL connections that are fairly fast. Works great on my colleagues machine that has a 58Mbps upload link. My problem is, I only have a 0.75Mbps upload stream available, which is a good thing, as we've managed to identify a problem with our uploading bits.

I've setup the uploader as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        maxChunkSize: 2000000, // 2MB
        multipart: false,
        progressInterval: 1000,
        bitrateInterval: 1000,

        chunkdone: function() {
            console.log('Chunk uploaded.');
        },

        chunkfail: function() {
            console.log('Chunk upload failed!');
        },

        chunksend: function() {
            console.log('Uploading next chunk.');
        },

        done: function(e, data) {
            console.log('Upload completed.');
            $('form#template_form input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        },

        fail : function(e, data) {
            console.log('Upload failed!');
            $('form#template_form input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        },

        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('div.progress span.meter').css('width', progress + '%');
            $('div.progress span.meter span, div.fileupload-progress .background-text')
                .html(progress + '% complete');
            console.log('Upload ' + progress + '% complete.');
        },

        start: function(e, data) {
            console.log('Upload started.');
            $('form#template_form input[type=submit]').attr({disabled: 'disabled'})
        }
    });
```

When I start uploading on the slow connection, I get to around 24% sometimes more, then the uploader just stops. I don't see any errors from the server, and also the chunkfail and fail error handlers never get triggered. Here's a snippet of my browser output:

```
Upload 22% complete. create:243
...
Upload 23% complete. create:243
XHR finished loading: "http://tmstest.personera.com/upload/". jquery.min.js:4
Chunk uploaded. create:219
Uploading next chunk. create:227
Upload 23% complete. create:243
...
Upload 23% complete. create:243
Upload 24% complete. create:243
...
Upload 24% complete. create:243
XHR finished loading: "http://tmstest.personera.com/upload/". jquery.min.js:4
Chunk uploaded. create:219
Uploading next chunk. create:227
Upload 24% complete. create:243
```

...and the output stops here, indicating the plugin isn't firing the progressall event anymore. Why is this, is there something wrong with the way I'm using it? I don't understand why it works on faster connections but fails on the slower connection.

I've setup Charles Proxy Debugger to try and throttle the localhost connection, but this way, the plugin never fails, so I guess I'm dealing with a timeout issue which is silently failing?

Is there a way to setup a timeout event handler for the plugin, so I can just get it to cancel and restart the current chunk?

Comment: Just another note, the Chrome networks console indefinitely shows the request made for the last chunk upload as (pending)

Comment: I'm attempting to create a setTimeout handler, that get's reset each time progressall executes. If my timeout limit is exceeded, I'm trying to restart uploading of the last chunk...